# Как привязать контекстное меню к нажатию именно правой кнопкой мыши на Button

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5

Код программы:

```
...
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.mwidget = QMainWindow(self)
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.Tool | QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint | QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
        self.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(Cfg.GX, Cfg.GY, Cfg.GW, Cfg.GH))
....
        self.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.CustomContextMenu)
        self.customContextMenuRequested.connect(self.show_context_menu)
        self.menu = qtw.QMenu(self)

        fix = self.menu.addAction("Зафиксировать панель")
        fix.triggered.connect(lambda: self.Fix())

        exit = self.menu.addAction("Выйти")
        exit.triggered.connect(lambda: sys.exit())
...
    def show_context_menu(self, point):
        self.menu.exec(self.mapToGlobal(point))
```

Comment: `show_context_menu` и так вызывает правым кликом мышки. Или у вас есть кнопка и вы хотите левой кнопкой кликать по ней, а правой вызывать меню?

Comment: см. коментарии ниже, вопрос решил сам.

Answer (score 0):

В главном окне:

```
self.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.CustomContextMenu)
self.customContextMenuRequested.connect(self.show_context_menu)
```

Привязка к QFrame с именем Label

```
self.Label.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.CustomContextMenu)
self.Label.customContextMenuRequested.connect(self.show_context_menu)
```

(не забыть поставить в то место где описывается сама кнопка, после self.Label = QFrame(self) иначе выдаст ошибку!)

Comment: А причем тут `Label`? Зачем это? О_о в вопросе не было ничего об этом

Comment: Исправил кнопку на Qbutton на QFrame в моем случае это не критично. Label это только название QFrame.